# Import tables into master latex file (like graphics).

Tags: tables, r

I am working with R and Latex and using R to generate a series of tables that I am exporting as a unique latex script each (e.g. it exports the table formatted for latex in a new script). I would like to import the table into a master latex file in the same way that you would graphics using the includegraphics command. Is there any analogue for this to import tables? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: since tables are just text a normal `\input` will be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main commands to include external `.tex` files into your document. `\input` and `\include`. If the things you're importing are tables, `\input` is 99% probably the one you want. See the differences between the two of them [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).